# DXL only finding new links in link module

Tags: oop, ibm-doors, ibm-rational

Have module A and module B and a link module to keep track of the links between the two.

In module A, I want a column that shows (for each object in module A) the object text, of the object it is linked to in object B.

i used the analysis Wizard and am having a problem - it only is finding NEW links created after the column is added. However, there ARE existing links but they are not showing up.

```
string linkModName = fullName(linkModItem) //verified linkModItem is valid

for l in all(o->linkModName) do {
         // dump object text - only displaying links created after?
         }
```

Only seems to work for links added after this column is created.

However - if I change the above to `for l in all(o->"*")` it will bring in the per-exisitng links.

Any point in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your older links are in the wrong Link Module. You can verify this by selecting `Link Module Name` from the Link Attributes list in the Analysis Wizard Column you are adding. Use all Link Modules so you can see all of the links and you should see that some are in a different Link Module than the one you are specifying.

[image: Screenshot of Link Module Name]

Comment: ok I started to get that hunch, based on the behavior but was told the link modules were set-up correctly...thanks.